# Custom Notification Not working with Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

I have created a Custom Notification. So basically, I want to inform all my Users of an upcoming Salesforce Maintenance Activity via this.

Custom Notification:

[image]

Here is my Process Builder:
[image: Object]

[image: Condition Criteria as User.LastLoginDate is changed and User is Active]

Condition Criteria as User.LastLoginDate is changed and User is Active

[image]

Anything I am missing in particular ?... I tried all options for Recipient but doesn't seem to get the Notification
Appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user logging in *does not* "modify" the User record in the traditional sense (the Last Modified fields are not updated, and no triggers or processes are executed). Instead, create a [Login Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_login_flow.htm&type=5) if you wish to provide this sort of notification.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, thanks for your response. So basically, user who is logging in is not modifying, but with user login action that record get modified, field user userlogindate ... Hence I took it as a criteria. With a login flow, can you guide me how do I start of and capture  user reference to display such a ref on login to a user

Comment: @VarunSFDC The example is [in the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_login_flow_examples.htm&type=5).

Comment: Hello sfdcfox, I see Welcome Screen missing in Flows in my instance, under interactions. Any idea what may have caused this.

Comment: Hello sfdcfox, I was successfully able to do it post following the documentation... Many thanks